# Why multiple instances of static class being created?

Tags: c#, dll, static

Suppose I have 3 DLL's. DLL #1 and #2 depend on DLL #3. DLL #3 contains a static class such as:

```
public class ImportTimer
{

    public static bool EnableProcessorTimerLogging { get; set; }
    public static bool EnableTimerLogging { get; set; }

    public static DateTime SourceDataDetectionTimestamp { get; set; }
    public static DateTime LastEndProcessTimestamp { get; set; }

    static ImportTimer()
    {
        EnableProcessorTimerLogging = false;
        EnableTimerLogging = false;

        SourceDataDetectionTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
        LastEndProcessTimestamp = DateTime.Now;
    }

    ...
}
```

All of the methods are static. DLL #1 and #2 do not know about each other (no dependencies on the other). When I invoke any method from DLL #1 and then invoke the same method on DLL #2, I see a new copy of the static object get created in DLL #2 (it is not using the same copy as DLL #1). So now I have 2 copies of ImportTimer when I only wanted one for both DLL's to share. How can I get the 2 DLL's to share the same static instance?

Comment: So then how can I have both DLL's refer to the same copy?

Comment: That's not a static class.  Having every member of a class be static does not make the class static.  A static class has the `static` keyword in the class declaration.

Comment: Classes are only static in the same appdomain. I'm pretty sure you only have one appdomain, but still...

Comment: @jmcilhinney Just extending your response. It is a good practice to mark class *static* if *all* the members are declared static.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your class is not static. The `static` constructor lets you initialize static members, [it's called automatically before your class is instantiated](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/k9x6w0hc.aspx).

[You can mark you class as `static`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-AU/library/79b3xss3.aspx) as well, by doing `static class ImportTimer`.

> a static class remains in memory for the lifetime of the application domain in which
>   your program resides.

However, this means you cannot have anything but static members in your class.

Alternatively, you can use a pattern to ensure that there is only 1 instance created, for that you can use the [Singleton Pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern).

In your `ImportTimer`, you want to set your constructor to `private`. Why? Because that way no one else but the class can create the instance.

Add a static property to get an instance of your class:

```
private static ImportTimer instance;
public static ImportTimer Instance 
{
    if(instance == null) instance = new ImportTimer();

    return instance;
}
```

Then in DLL #1 and #2, you can use `ImportTimer.Instance` to get the shared, static instance.

Comment: I tried creating a static class and it is still somehow creating 2 copies of the object.

Comment: Is it different App Domains? Is it the same application? If you run the application twice, you will still have 2 objects.

Comment: That explains it! It's only static in the same AppDomain.

Comment: I was under the impression that making class static is enough to ensure there is only one instance created of the class. If I don't implement a pattern, but my class is static, I could still have two instances of the same class?